# Classifying rows based on if a date falls within a given date range

Tags: r, date, dplyr

Looking to classify an existing event date, based on if it falls within 2 dates in another column

**My Raw data looks like this:**

| study_id | Event | Event_Date | Event_Result | Pre1 | CheckUp | Post1 | Pre2 | CheckUp2 | Post2 | Pre3 | CheckUp3 | Post3 | Pre4 | CheckUp4 | Post4 | Pre5 | CheckUp5 | Post5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | event1 | 5/4/2012 | 1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 |
| 1 | event1 | 5/15/2012 | 1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 |
| 1 | event1 | 6/5/2012 | 1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 |
| 1 | event1 | 7/3/2012 | 0.8 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 |
| 2 | event2 | 8/14/2012 | 1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 |
| 2 | event2 | 9/11/2012 | 1.2 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 |
| 2 | event1 | 9/21/2012 | 1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 |
| 3 | event1 | 10/9/2012 | 1.1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 |
| 3 | event1 | 10/23/2012 | 1.1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 |
| 3 | event2 | 10/25/2012 | 1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 |
| 4 | event2 | 11/2/2012 | 1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 |
| 4 | event1 | 11/13/2012 | 1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 |

**Expected Outcome** I am hoping to have a column for each interval rule (see what I have tried section below for interval details, but essentially a total of 10 extra columns), and if the event_Date falls within Interval rule, mark it as TRUE, otherwise false. I was able to do this in Excel, but looking for a solution in R.

See example below.

| personID | Event_Date | Event_Result | Pre1 | CheckUp | Post1 | Pre2 | CheckUp2 | Post2 | Pre3 | CheckUp3 | Post3 | Pre4 | CheckUp4 | Post4 | Pre5 | CheckUp5 | Post5 | Interval1 | Interval2 | Interval3 | Interval4 | Interval5 | Interval6 | Interval7 | Interval8 | Interval9 | Interval10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5/4/2012 | 1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 1 | 5/15/2012 | 1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 1 | 6/5/2012 | 1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 2 | 7/3/2012 | 0.8 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 2 | 8/14/2012 | 1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 3 | 9/11/2012 | 1.2 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 3 | 9/21/2012 | 1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 3 | 10/9/2012 | 1.1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 4 | 10/23/2012 | 1.1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 4 | 10/25/2012 | 1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 4 | 11/2/2012 | 1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 5 | 11/13/2012 | 1 | 7/23/2012 | 10/23/2012 | 1/23/2013 | 11/25/2013 | 2/25/2014 | 5/25/2014 | 8/1/2014 | 11/1/2014 | 2/1/2015 | 7/4/2015 | 10/4/2015 | 1/4/2016 | 7/4/2016 | 10/4/2016 | 1/4/2017 | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |

**What I have Tried**
I have tried to create the intervals to look at the Event_Result and see if it falls within a Range based on the Post, Pre and CheckUp dates. The intervals rules I care about are the following 10:

Interval1 = If EventDate >= Pre1 AND EvenDate <= CheckUp

Interval2 = If EventDate > CheckUp AND EvenDate <= Post1

Interval3 = If EventDate >= Pre2 AND EvenDate <= CheckUp2

Interval4 = If EventDate > CheckUp2 AND EvenDate <= Post2

*

*

Interval9 = If EventDate >= Pre5 AND EventDate <= CheckUp5

Interval10 = If EventDate > CheckUp5 AND EventDate <= Post5

I tried using LUBRIDATE with no luck. As I mentioned I was able to do this in Excel, but just looking for an approach in R (open to LUBRIDATE, DPLYR, or other libraries)

INTERVAL_1  <- interval(ymd(data_merged$Pre1), ymd(data_merged$EventDate))

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  person_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  event_date = ymd(c("20120504",
                     "20120515",
                     "20120605",
                     "20120703",
                     "20120814",
                     "20120911",
                     "20120921",
                     "20121009"))
)

pre1 <- ymd("20120723")
checkup <- ymd("20121023")
post1 <- ymd("20130123")

interval1 <- interval(pre1, checkup)
interval2 <- interval(checkup, post1)

df %>%
  mutate(
    int1 = event_date %within% interval1,
    int2 = event_date %within% interval2
  )
```

```
  person_id event_date  int1  int2
1         1 2012-05-04 FALSE FALSE
2         1 2012-05-15 FALSE FALSE
3         1 2012-06-05 FALSE FALSE
4         2 2012-07-03 FALSE FALSE
5         2 2012-08-14  TRUE FALSE
6         3 2012-09-11  TRUE FALSE
7         3 2012-09-21  TRUE FALSE
8         3 2012-10-09  TRUE FALSE
```

another option

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  person_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  event_date = ymd(c("20120504",
                     "20120515",
                     "20120605",
                     "20120703",
                     "20120814",
                     "20120911",
                     "20120921",
                     "20121009")),
  pre1 = ymd("20120723"),
  checkup = ymd("20121023"),
  post1 = ymd("20130123")
)

df %>%
  mutate(
    int1 = event_date %within% interval(pre1, checkup),
    int2 = event_date %within% interval(checkup, post1)
  )
```

```
  person_id event_date       pre1    checkup      post1  int1  int2
1         1 2012-05-04 2012-07-23 2012-10-23 2013-01-23 FALSE FALSE
2         1 2012-05-15 2012-07-23 2012-10-23 2013-01-23 FALSE FALSE
3         1 2012-06-05 2012-07-23 2012-10-23 2013-01-23 FALSE FALSE
4         2 2012-07-03 2012-07-23 2012-10-23 2013-01-23 FALSE FALSE
5         2 2012-08-14 2012-07-23 2012-10-23 2013-01-23  TRUE FALSE
6         3 2012-09-11 2012-07-23 2012-10-23 2013-01-23  TRUE FALSE
7         3 2012-09-21 2012-07-23 2012-10-23 2013-01-23  TRUE FALSE
8         3 2012-10-09 2012-07-23 2012-10-23 2013-01-23  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. I do have over 1000+ rows and at least 15 columns. Is there a way to create the pre1, checkup, post1 automatically instead of declaring them manually?

Comment: maybe, you can assign in your data frame just like you do. i have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach to try.

First, make sure your dates are in `Date` format. Rename `CheckUp` to `CheckUp1` so consistent with other columns.

Then, you can try pivoting your data into long form with `pivot_longer`, and use `group_by` to look at event dates. In this case, a column was created to evaluate if event date was in interval between pre and checkup, and a second column for checkup to post.

After that, you can put your result into wide format again, and join with original data.

```
library(tidyverse)

prep_data <- raw_data %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with(c("Pre", "CheckUp", "Post")), as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
         Event_Date = as.Date(Event_Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  rename(CheckUp1 = CheckUp)

prep_data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with(c("Pre", "CheckUp", "Post")), names_to = c("Event_Type", "Number"), names_pattern = "(\\w+)(\\d+)") %>%
  group_by(study_id, Event, Event_Date, Event_Result, Number) %>%
  mutate(interval_pre = Event_Date >= value[Event_Type == "Pre"] & Event_Date <= value[Event_Type == "CheckUp"],
         interval_post = Event_Date > value[Event_Type == "CheckUp"] & Event_Date <= value[Event_Type == "Post"]) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(study_id, Event, Event_Date, Event_Result), names_from = Number, values_from = c("interval_pre", "interval_post"), values_fn = first) %>%
  right_join(prep_data %>% select(study_id, Event, Event_Date, Event_Result))
```

**Output**

```
   study_id Event  Event_Date Event_Result interval_pre_1 interval_pre_2 interval_pre_3 interval_pre_4 interval_pre_5 interval_post_1 interval_post_2 interval_post_3 interval_post_4 interval_post_5
      <int> <chr>  <date>            <dbl> <lgl>          <lgl>          <lgl>          <lgl>          <lgl>          <lgl>           <lgl>           <lgl>           <lgl>           <lgl>          
 1        1 event1 2012-05-04          1   FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE          
 2        1 event1 2012-05-15          1   FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE          
 3        1 event1 2012-06-05          1   FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE          
 4        1 event1 2012-07-03          0.8 FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE          
 5        2 event2 2012-08-14          1   TRUE           FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE          
 6        2 event2 2012-09-11          1.2 TRUE           FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE          
 7        2 event1 2012-09-21          1   TRUE           FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE          
 8        3 event1 2012-10-09          1.1 TRUE           FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE          
 9        3 event1 2012-10-23          1.1 TRUE           FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE          
10        3 event2 2012-10-25          1   FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          TRUE            FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE          
11        4 event2 2012-11-02          1   FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          TRUE            FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE          
12        4 event1 2012-11-13          1   FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          TRUE            FALSE           FALSE           FALSE           FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simplistic way to do that in **base R** is as follow:

```
df2<-apply(df[,c(3,5:ncol(df))], 2, function(x) as.Date(x, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
df2 <- data.frame(df2)
attach(df2)
df2$Interval1 <- Event_Date >= Pre1 & Event_Date <= CheckUp
df2$Interval2 <- Event_Date > CheckUp & Event_Date <= Post1
# and so on and so forth
```